# How to ORDER BY relevance in SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm not sure the correct way to even phrase this question. I have an SQLite database containing thousands of images ids. Each image is tagged with a bunch of words. The idea is you select some words in the UI, and then it displays the corresponding images to you. Pretty simple.

My table for image tags looks something like this...

```
imageId    |    tags
____________________

   1            red
   1            green

   2            blue
   2            yellow

   3            red
   3            yellow

   etc...
```

Currently, I'm using a simple WHERE IN to just get all the image ids like so...

```
SELECT imageId FROM tagsTable WHERE tags IN ('red','green','blue')
```

...but now I need to rank the image ids I get in terms of relevance. So for example if I ask for 'red' and 'yellow', I want to have image id 3 first in my results, before id's 1 and 2.

It seems like a straightforward enough thing to do, but I can't figure it out?

Comment: Note that your original query can return duplicates.

Comment: It can? I've never gotten any duplicate IDs back when I test it?

Comment: Your query would return `1` twice for your sample data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40c40/1 - You would need to use `DISTINCT` here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT imageId
FROM tagsTable
WHERE tags IN ('red','yellow')
GROUP BY imageId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Will return the imageIDs with the most matches first.

Comment: @AzzyDude - It will work with DISTINCT - But DISTINCT will have no effect here since we already group by `imageId` - So there can't be any duplicates. But it's fine, if you want to build the query dynamicly, and add the last two lines conditionally. But you could also just use `GROUP BY imageId` instead of `DISTINCT` (same effect) and just add the last line when needed.